# Animate Columns in mmqgis plugin

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

I'm trying to use Animate Columns in MMQGIS plugin. I don't have a lot of input as of how to use it, apart from the instructions here: http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

What I don't understand is how to calculate the offset values. The instructions say:

> Offsets for points may be calculated by:  offset_long = (end_long -
>   start_long)   offset_lat = (end_lat - start_lat)

Does that mean I should have a column subtracting the starting Lat from the ending Lat etc.? eg. 2538295.09836-2544008.68716 = -5713.5888099. But that doesn't make sense to me. Alternatively, I tried having a text column with the 2538295.09836-2544008.68716. But the tool, doesn't recognize text columns.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, your approach of adding numeric columns that subtract start and end lon/lat values is correct. The offsets define how far the point features are moved in horizontal / vertical direction.

> The objects are moved over the specified Duration number of frames in a straight line based on the offsets specified in the Latitude Offset Column and Longitude Offset Column.

(source: http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/)